# iOS plugin for Unity returning NSArray back to c#

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out how to return a NSArray back to unity c#. I didn't find anything.

I have a function on my .mm that has a NSArray to return, but I don't know which type I return and how to get it from Unity.

My NSArray contains NSString.

Comment: There might be ways to achieve this directly, but most developers seem to go via JSON

Comment: Thanks @Kay, I think is more easy to return a big char with JSON rather than suffer trying to figure out how to do it in another ways.

Comment: @Kay, you know how to get [const char *] from obj-c in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in the question's comments section, JSON is the easiest way to achieve this. In your Objective-C class *IOS.**mm*** you need something like:

```
extern "C" {
    char* GetMyJSONStringIOS () {
        MyClass* myInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
        NSString* str = [myInstance convertToJSON];
        char* s = cStringCopy([str UTF8String]);
        return s;
    }
    char* cStringCopy(const char* string) {
        char* res = (char*)malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
        strcpy(res, string);
        return res;
    }
}
```

In your C# class *IOSWrapper.cs*

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
static extern string GetMyJSONStringIOS ();

public static string GetMyJSONString () {
    string json;
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_IPHONE
    json = GetMyJSONStringIOS ();
#else
    json = "Dont know";
#endif
    }
    return json;
}
```

The method `cStringCopy` is used internally to copy from const char* to char*.

Comment: Thanks for help @Kay. But I found another way. I'm converting my NSArray to JSON and i'm returning it as const char *. At Unity, I user Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to convert Intptr returning value. It Works Fine! after that I can use JSON parse to get my values.

Comment: @Dyego You should answer your own question. so that someone else can use that method. the one u found.